# design an algorithm to determine whether there exists such a key which is equal to the summation of other two keys in the array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, mergesort

i'm trying to solve this problem: given an array containing n keys determine whether there exists such a key that is equal to sum of other two keys in array. if yes, print them out.
I'm using mergesort to sort the array and then checking for keys. but (for loop) inside summation function somehow fails to increment every time. i've tried (while loop) and several other ways. nothing works. any ideas?

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge_sort(int input_array[], int first_element, int last_element);
void merge(int input_array[], int first_element, int middle_element,
           int last_element);
void find_summation(int input_array[], int first_element, int last_element);

int total_elements;
int main() {
  int input_array[100];
  printf("\nEnter number of elements in the array : ");
  scanf("%d", &total_elements);

  int i = 0;
  printf("\nEnter %d array elements: ", total_elements);
  while (i < total_elements) {
    scanf("%d", &input_array[i]);
    i++;
  }
  merge_sort(input_array, 0, total_elements - 1);

  printf("\nSorted Array: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < total_elements; i++) {
    printf("%d ", input_array[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");
  find_summation(input_array, 0, total_elements - 1);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}

void find_summation(int input_array[], int first_element, int last_element) {
  bool found;

  last_element = total_elements - 1;
  int j = 2;
  int current_num;

  for (int j = 2; j <= last_element;) {
    current_num = input_array[j];
    while ((first_element < last_element)) {
      int a = input_array[first_element];
      int b = input_array[last_element];
      int summation = a + b;
      printf("summation %d\n", summation);
      if (summation == current_num) {
        found = true;

      } else if (summation > current_num) {
        last_element--;

      } else if (summation < current_num) {
        first_element++;
      }
      if (found) {
        printf("\nKey: %d > sum of Keys: %d & %d", current_num, a,
               current_num - a);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

void merge(int input_array[], int first_element, int middle_element,
           int last_element) {
  int m = (middle_element - first_element) + 1;
  int n = last_element - middle_element;

  int left_array[m];
  int right_array[n];

  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    left_array[i] = input_array[first_element + i];
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    right_array[j] = input_array[(middle_element + 1) + j];
  }

  int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
  k = first_element;
  while (i < m && j < n) {
    if (left_array[i] <= right_array[j]) {
      input_array[k] = left_array[i++];

    } else {
      input_array[k] = right_array[j++];
    }
    k++;
  }

  while (i < m) {
    input_array[k++] = left_array[i++];
  }

  while (j < n) {
    input_array[k++] = right_array[j++];
  }
}

void merge_sort(int input_array[], int first_element, int last_element) {
  if (first_element < last_element) {
    int middle_element = (first_element + last_element) / 2;

    merge_sort(input_array, first_element, middle_element);
    merge_sort(input_array, middle_element + 1, last_element);

    merge(input_array, first_element, middle_element, last_element);
  } else
    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if `first_elem < last_elem` always hold true in your `find_summation` function ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by failing to increment here? Have you run the code line by line in a debugger to see how it behaves?

Comment: `if(found) { break; }` will prevent finding same sum more than once if there are duplicate numbers in the array.

Comment: Side note: Did you have a look at [mre]? Assuming merge sort works correctly, which I'd conclude from the question's style, your minimal example might look like: `int main() { int input[] = { 7, 10, 12 }; find_summation(input, 0, sizeof(input)/sizeof(*input) - 1); }`, dropping all the sorting functions...

Comment: Hint: What happens with inner while loop after it was run one single time? Have a close look at your loop condition! (If you don't get it by analysing code, try debugging...) Apropos, why the double parentheses? They serve nothing for, just make reading the code harder.

Comment: `last_element = total_elements - 1;` – you pass last_element correctly as argument already, no need to recalculate, so best drop that line entirely (although it wouldn't hurt in concrete example). You won't need to keep `total_elements` as global variable either but can make it local to `main` then. Generally: Avoid global variables as much as possible (or reasonable at least), they often are the source of pretty much trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for guidance and support. Finally got the code to work on all the cases. original code had a lot of mistakes. including control flow and logical errors. i have fixed the code now. solution is posted below:
Test Case: 18 23 4 35 99 67 198 20 38 55 2 19 487 11 40 10 13 27 22

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge_sort(int input_array[], int first_element, int last_element);
void merge(int input_array[], int first_element, int middle_element,
           int last_element);
void find_summation(int input_array[], int first_element, int last_element);
int binary_search(int input_array[], int first_element, int last_element,
                  int difference);


int main() {
  int total_elements;
  int input_array[100];
  printf("\nEnter number of elements in the array : ");
  scanf("%d", &total_elements);

  int i = 0;
  printf("\nEnter %d array elements: ", total_elements);
  while (i < total_elements) {
    scanf("%d", &input_array[i]);
    i++;
  }
  merge_sort(input_array, 0, total_elements - 1);

  printf("\nSorted Array: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < total_elements; i++) {
    printf("%d ", input_array[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");
  find_summation(input_array, 0, total_elements);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}

void find_summation(int input_array[], int first_element, int last_element) {
  for (int j = 0; j <= last_element; j++) {
    int current_num = input_array[j];

    // printf("current_num and j: %d %d\n", current_num, j);

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
      int element = input_array[i];
      int element_found =
          binary_search(input_array, first_element, j, (current_num - element));

      if (element_found > 0) {
        if (element != (current_num - element))
          printf("\nKey: %d > sum of Keys: %d & %d", current_num, element,
                 current_num - element);

      }  
    }    
  }
}
int binary_search(int input_array[], int first_element, int last_element,
                  int difference) {
  bool found;
  int current_num;

  int middle_element = (first_element + last_element) / 2;
  if ((last_element >= first_element) && (first_element < middle_element)) {
    // int middle_element = (first_element + last_element) / 2;
    /*
        while ((last_element - first_element) <= 2) {
          return binary_search(input_array, middle_element + 1, last_element,
                               difference);
        }*/
    if (input_array[middle_element] == difference) {
      return middle_element;
    }

    if (input_array[middle_element] > difference) {
      return binary_search(input_array, first_element, middle_element - 1,
                           difference);
    }

    return binary_search(input_array, middle_element + 1, last_element,
                         difference);
  }
  return -1;
}
void merge(int input_array[], int first_element, int middle_element,
           int last_element) {
  int m = (middle_element - first_element) + 1;
  int n = last_element - middle_element;

  int left_array[m];
  int right_array[n];

  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    left_array[i] = input_array[first_element + i];
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    right_array[j] = input_array[(middle_element + 1) + j];
  }

  int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
  k = first_element;
  while (i < m && j < n) {
    if (left_array[i] <= right_array[j]) {
      input_array[k] = left_array[i++];

    } else {
      input_array[k] = right_array[j++];
    }
    k++;
  }

  while (i < m) {
    input_array[k++] = left_array[i++];
  }

  while (j < n) {
    input_array[k++] = right_array[j++];
  }
}

void merge_sort(int input_array[], int first_element, int last_element) {
  if (first_element < last_element) {
    int middle_element = (first_element + last_element) / 2;

    merge_sort(input_array, first_element, middle_element);
    merge_sort(input_array, middle_element + 1, last_element);

    merge(input_array, first_element, middle_element, last_element);
  } else
    return;
}
```

Comment: Is there a restriction that duplicate (equal) keys are not allowed?

Comment: Yes, we have to try and minimize duplicate keys as much as we can, while maintaining the efficiency of algorithm.